# Pentaho report design.Adding two columns from different sub reports

Tags: pentaho

I have a main report and few subreports.
In the main report I have a total(sum) for one of the columns as 'Total A'
And in one of the sub reports I have a total for another column as 'Total B'

Now i want a grandtotal for those two columns 
i.e ([Total A]+[Total B])in one feild.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the Open Formula with ([Total A]+[Total B]) as the expression.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the functions of the subreports cannot be exported. So [Total A] and [Total B] from each subreport are not available in the main report, even if set properly in the "Export Parameters" section of the subreport.

¿Anyone else experiencing this problem?